# Avoid automatically XML-Tag Creation in SQL-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have got an table in SQL-Server, where I have XML stored in one column.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
[MyId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
[MyContent] [xml] NULL
)
```

The xml in the column "MyContent" looks like this:

```
<Account id="1">
    <Name>Bill</Name>
</Account>
```

Now I want to concatenate all columns to one big xml.
I tried to do that with "for xml" function in SQL-Server:

```
select  
   MyContent 
from MyTable
for xml path('')
```

The XML, that is created looks like this:

```
<MyContent>
   <Account id="1">
      <Name>Bill</Name>
   </Account>
</MyContent>
<MyContent>
   <Account id="2">
      <Name>John</Name>
   </Account>
</MyContent>
```

But that is not what I needed, I need the XML without the created "MyContent" Tags, so what I need is this:

```
<Account id="1">
   <Name>Bill</Name>
</Account>
<Account id="2">
   <Name>John</Name>
</Account>
```

Is there any way to avoid the Tag creation for the column name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `*` as column alias.

[Columns with a Name Specified as a Wildcard Character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500154.aspx)

```
select  
   MyContent as [*]
from MyTable
for xml path('')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(MyContent)
VALUES 
    ('<Account id="1"><Name>Bill</Name></Account>'), 
    ('<Account id="2"><Name>Jack</Name></Account>')

SELECT [*] = MyContent 
FROM dbo.MyTable
FOR XML PATH ('')
```

**Output:**

```
<Account id="1">
  <Name>Bill</Name>
</Account>
<Account id="2">
  <Name>Jack</Name>
</Account>
```

Comment: Thanks, Mikael was a litle bit faster, so I will accept his answer